# Installing Npm, node on a shared hosting plan WITHOUT SSH

Tags: node.js, apache, npm

As the title says, I'm trying to install npm, node etc. on a shared plan which doesn't have SSH, running Apache.

Is that possible in any way?
Thanks.

Comment: Which OS is the host running?

Comment: If you do not have SSH, I assume you do not have shell access to this system at all.  So unless the provider has something on its administration web pages, you cannot do it.

Comment: @AshleyRedmanBSc Linux

Comment: There are ways to do it if you had the right permissions, something like a sh file that was written to install it and configure correctly, however as @Nic3500 mentions, if you dont have shell access, you more than likely don't have permissions to install anything, just write in terms of uploading files. For node applications, I would look more towards using something such as DigitalOcean or Heroku to host it, at least that way, these things get installed at the beginning and you get ssh access.